# Bitstamp order book history

Tags: api, bitstamp, historical-trade-data

The current state of Bitstamps order book is available here:
https://www.bitstamp.net/api/order_book/

I want to analyze the history of the order book.

Do someone know if its available?

Comment: Can you explain why you need it at a third party if the data is already there in the API?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoincharts.com has the ["market depth" for Bitstamp](http://bitcoincharts.com/markets/bitstampUSD_depth.html), which is just what you are asking for. It is presented both as a graph and a table with actual bid and ask volumes. There is a free [API](http://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/) for much of their data, but (added in edit) to my surprise, the orderbook data does not seem available that way. If it will help you will depend on your application: There is a 15 minute delay.

There are many other sites presenting visualizations of the orderbooks of exchanges; one example is [Bitcoinity.org's Bitstamp page](http://bitcoinity.org/markets/bitstamp/USD). But I   am not aware of any other than Bitcoincharts.com that provides a public API.

UPDATE:

The question has been changed from asking if this data is available "at a third party" to whether it is available at all. Yes, it is available, from the first party (Bitstamp), via the API link provided in the question itself.

Comment: The question (unclearly) asks for the historic data of the orderbook not the current orderbook data. What you are pointing at is current orderbook data.

Answer (score 1):

This data is available for sale [here](https://www.kaiko.com/collections/exchanges-order-books)

> Kaiko is the only company which stores and distributes order books for Bitcoin and Ethereum. For Bitcoin, historical data traces all the way back to August 2015. For Ethereum (ETH only, not ETC), data starts in June 2016.